# Why share url to Facebook via android intent doesn't work?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I have the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);
// determine fb app
List<ResolveInfo> matches = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
    String pkg = info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase();
    if (pkg.startsWith("com.facebook.katana") || pkg.startsWith("com.facebook.lite")) {
        intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
    }
}
context.startActivity(intent);
```

About 100-200 users press the share button of which more than 70% have an app installed. That would mean 70-150 shares per day. However I get maybe one share per day! I think that most of the time the FB app ignores the link, it only opens the share dialog but WITHOUT THE LINK. On my mobile device it works ok (the link is part of the share) but for others it is not.

Am I doing something wrong? Or Facebook doesn't allow to share links like this?

Comment: Where did you read about using EXTRA_TEXT to pass a URL to the Facebook app?

Comment: It was on stackoverflow some time ago, doesn't seem to be reliable though

Comment: I would suggest using https://developers.facebook.com/docs as a source of what you can do instead of old stackoverflow posts

Comment: I'm trying to keep my apk size small(right now under 2 MB), if I include the full facebook sdk it will be too large and fewer people will download it.

Comment: How big will it become if you add the Facebook SDK?

Comment: Too big! The library is too large for me to include, I would only use if it were something like 150-200KB. This is because I do not wish to increase the apk over 2MB. If achieving this is not possible, than bye bye facebook.

Comment: It is less then 200kB

Comment: I have downloaded the fb sdk again: each apk sample(demonstrating basic functionality) has at least 1.8 MB, furthermore the "facebook-android-sdk-4.21.1.aar" has 933 KB. So which library are you referring to?

Comment: How big the download is doesn't matter. The thing that matters is how much bigger your app becomes.